# SwiftUI multiple sheets: dismiss animation broken

Tags: swiftui, presentation

I have button1, showing sheet1 when pressed. Then I have a toggle, showing a button2, which in turn presents sheet2 when pressed.

If I just press button1, the sheet shows and dismisses with animation. If, however, I press the toggle, which shows button2, and then press button1, the sheet dismiss animation is broken (simply doesn't animate).

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var showSheetButton2 = false
@State private var showSheet1 = false
@State private var showSheet2 = false

var body: some View {

    VStack {
        Toggle("Show Sheet Button 2", isOn: $showSheetButton2)

        Button(action: {
            showSheet1.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("Show Sheet 1")
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet1, content: {
            Button(action: {
                showSheet1 = false
            }, label: {
                Text("Dismiss")
            })
        })

        if showSheetButton2 {
            Button(action: {
                showSheet2.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Show Sheet 2")
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet2, content: {
                Button(action: {
                    showSheet2 = false
                }, label: {
                    Text("Dismiss")
                })
            })
        }
    }.padding()
}
}
```

EDIT:

Fixed in iOS 14.5:

> You can now apply multiple sheet(isPresented:onDismiss:content:) and
> fullScreenCover(item:onDismiss:content:) modifiers in the same view
> hierarchy. (74246633)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this sheet inside If statement is destroying animation. Please try to add EmptyView outside this if statement and assign sheet to that view.

```
        if showSheetButton2 {
            Button(action: {
                showSheet2.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Show Sheet 2")
            })
        }
        EmptyView()
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet2, content: {
                Button(action: {
                    showSheet2 = false
                }, label: {
                    Text("Dismiss")
                })
            })
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't even need an empty view. If I move the sheets to the outer VStack, it already works. Problem is, because of reasons, I need them attached to the subview. Because in my case, those views come from another module, so the App using those views doesn't see the sheet modifiers, it just shows/hide them, causing the glitch.